# How to resolve recv failure connection reset by peer

Tags: git, fatal-error, recv

i'm trying to `git push` to my local branch, yesterday was fine. but, today I got
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nufolder/DSC.git/': Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error on my vscode and my terminal

i've tried changing my wifi to my mobile hotspot, and then i tried `git gc` to clear. before i change to mobile hotspot `git pull` was having this error too.

how to fix this?